# Can I put an object and an array together inside another array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two objects which i want to group together in an object then place them both inside an array.

```
vm.data = {};
vm.category_name_image = [] ;

getProductFunc=function(){

        $http.get(ConfigCnst.apiUrl+'?route=categories').success(function (res) {
            //console.log(res);
            var sub_category = res;
            console.log(sub_category);
            var bagmankey = '-JweP7imFLfnh96iwn-c';
            //console.log(bagmankey);
            angular.forEach(sub_category, function (value, key) {
                if (value.parentKey == bagmankey ) {
                // where i loop         
                    vm.data.name = value.name;
                    vm.data.picture = value.image;

                    var selected = {
                            vm.data.name,
                            vm.data.picture
                        } // Where I group the two.

                        vm.category_name_image.push(seleted);
                        // where i want to place the both.


                }

            });


            });
    }
```

I seem to be getting an error when I place both vm.data.name and vm.data.picture, inside the object selected.

I want my output like this: [ {name,picture},{name,picture},{name,picture} ]

Comment: "_I seem to be getting an error_" You should tell us what the error is. Also, this looks like javascript but is tagged java. You should fix that.

Comment: What about creating an object model, and then creating an array based on the model as well?

Comment: @Takendarkk, my controller gets undefined...

Comment: @FriarBob, how exactly do I do that? Im pretty new with javascript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create object property without name:

```
//object with properties 'name' & 'picture'
var selected = {
    name: vm.data.name,
    picture: vm.data.picture
}
```

or You can use array, if You really need use only data (bad way):

```
var selected = [
    vm.data.name,
    vm.data.picture
]
```

Comment: You need to explain what each of those are.

Comment: @user3335966 i got it, it seems my error was syntax, i didnt add "name:" with vm.data.name.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects are key value pairs. You are missing the key when you construct the object

```
var selected = {
    name: vm.data.name,
    picture: vm.data.picture
} // Where I group the two.
```

You could directly push by the way without using `selected`

```
vm.category_name_image.push({
    name: vm.data.name,
    picture: vm.data.picture
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your example.

```
var selected = {
    vm.data.name,
    vm.data.picture
}; // Where I group the two.

vm.category_name_image.push(seleted);
// where i want to place the both.
```

It should be

```
//it would be better to assign name and picture to properties of the object
var selected = {
    name: vm.data.name, 
    picture: vm.data.picture
}; // Where I group the two.

//you had a typo here --- it should be selected not seleted
vm.category_name_image.push(selected);
// where i want to place the both.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// where i loop         
vm.data.name = value.name;
vm.data.picture = value.image;
var selected = {
    vm.data.name,
    vm.data.picture
} // Where I group the two.

vm.category_name_image.push(seleted);
// where i want to place the both.
}
```

You can use below code instead

```
vm.category_name_image.push({name:value.name, picture:value.image});
```